# Set width:100% relative to another object for an object that needs to be fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/gsnfzn35/3/

It's a bit funky to describe, click the toggle drawer button. A pull out drawer on the right shows up. That pull out drawer is one container, but has 2 key components. The first component is all the content at the top. The last component is a "fixed row" on the bottom:

```
<div class="scroll-fixed-row" style="width:100%;text-align: right">
  <p>
    FIXED FINAL ROW
  </p>
</div>
```

This row SHOULD be the width of the pull out drawer, whatever that width is; NOT the width of the screen. Currently though, if you inspect element with the `width:100%`, you see that the width is the width of the screen, not the pull out drawer. Another way to see this is in the fact that when there's `width:100%;text-align:right`, the text is off screen, pulled to the right of the row that is too wide. Remove the `width:100%` and you can see the text again.

I'm guessing this is due to the fact that the `scroll-fixed-row` is fixed, and therefore, its taking width from the screen, not the pull out drawer itself. But this fixed is necessary, because that `scroll-fixed-row` needs to stay at the bottom even though the rest of the pull out drawer scrolls. Given that constraint, how can I set the width of the `scroll-fixed-row` to be the width of the pull out drawer, for any screen (full responsiveness) WITHOUT having to provide specific width in pixels based on media queries?

The reason I'm asking this is because I would like to divide the `scroll-fixed-row` into 2 "sections" using either a table and 2 `<td width="50%">` or using Bootstrap grid and 2 `<div class="col-xs-6">` in a row. In the current implementation (NOT in the Fiddle), the content in the 2nd grid just gets pushed off page (same issue now) because the table width is inheriting from the screen. I think I can figure that part out if someone can help me answer this question.

Comment: you can user jQuery to get the width of draw out container every time it's drawn out. Then, you can set the width of fixed row equal to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width can be solved by using `inherit` instead of `100%`, this will make a `fixed` element get the width of its parent, in your case `.container.scroll`. I noticed that you have padding added to parent, the inherited width will include paddings and so the `fixed` element will overlay the scrollbars.

Code:

```
.scroll-fixed-row {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: inherit; /* get width from parent */
  bottom: 0; /* stick to bottom */
  right: 0; /* fix offset caused by padding */
}
```

Another thing I noticed that in your code is that you are using `margin-top: 70px` on `.scroll` to offset it from the fixed red nav, this causes the the bottom part that is out of viewport to be invisible, especially the bottom scroll arrow. I've changed it to the following:

```
.scroll {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px; /* offset from top (nav height) */
  height: calc(100% - 70px); /* calculate height minus the top offset */
}
```

If you wanted to prevent the fixed element from overlapping the scrollbars, you could apply `pointer-events: none` and add another wrapper in the HTML that gets a `15px` spacing like the content, for better consistency:

```
.scroll-fixed-row {
  ...
  pointer-events:none; /* disables mouse functionality to enable scrollbar control */
}

.scroll-fixed-row .inner {
  border-top:2px solid red;
  background:lightblue;
  margin:0 30px 0 15px;
  pointer-events:auto; /* allows mouse functionality */
}
```

jsFiddle demo - scrollbar overlap: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/guufj4a0/

jsFiddle demo - additional wrapper: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/d6wwk51b/